# Can we paint religious images with laterite?

Tags: sin, tulasi, art

I'm planning to make an image of Mahalakshmi and shankh-chakra on my tulasi-thara (tulsi-vrindavan) to surprise my mother as she's always wanted to have it painted (just plain white right now) but we never had the money for it.

I'm gonna be painting it on the front of the tulsi-vrindavan using natural laterite from the soil near our garden. I don't think I've heard anything against using things like mud/laterite for painting Hindu gods, but I just wanted to ask here to make sure there's nothing wrong with it. Thanks :P